# How to select an svg element with title using cypress?

Tags: hover, cypress

I want to hover on a `svg` element inside a `div` element with class `main`. This `svg` element has the title tag `Header element`

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div>
                <svg></svg>
                <span> //want to hover on this element
                    <svg>
                        <title>Header element</title>
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As seen from the code above, I want to hover on `span` element that contains the `svg` with the title `Header element`.

I have tried using the code:

```js
cy.get(`.main>div`)
    .contains('svg', 'Header element')
    .trigger('mouseover')
```

but this is not working.

Could someone help me locate this span element using Cypress. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are selecting the svg but want to hover the span, so add a parent selector

```js
cy.get(`.main>div`)
  .contains('svg', 'Header element')
  .parent('span')
  .trigger('mouseover')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `.` (class selector)

```
cy.get(`.main>div`)
    .contains('svg', 'Header element')
    .triggers('mouseover')
```